# taking image snapshot of CATiledLayer-backed view in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, calayer, catiledlayer

I've got a custom map view which is made of a `UIScrollView`. The scroll view's subview is backed by a `CATiledLayer`. Everything works great here. Panning & zooming loads up new map tiles and everything performs well.

What I want to do is capture frames of video of animations to this scroll view. Essentially, I want to create a video of animated changes to the scroll view's `contentOffset` and `zoomScale`.

I know that the concept is sound as I can get the private API function `UIGetScreenImage()` to capture the app's screen at, say, 10fps, combine these images, and I get playback animations that are smooth and have the timing curves used by the scroll view animations.

My problem, of course, is that I can't use the private API. Going through the alternatives outlined by Apple [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/61338) leaves me with pretty much one supposedly valid option: asking a `CALayer` to `renderInContext` and taking a `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` from that.

This just doesn't seem to work with `CATiledLayer`-backed views, though. A blocky, un-zoomed image is what is captured, as if the higher-resolution tiles never load. This somewhat makes sense given that `CATiledLayer` draws in background threads for performance and calling `renderInContext` from the main thread might not catch these updates. The result is similar even if I render the tiled layer's `presentationLayer` as well.

Is there an Apple-sanctioned way of capturing an image of a `CATiledLayer`-backed view during the course of the containing scroll view's animations? Or at any point, for that matter?

Comment: Someone posted the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526545/render-large-catiledlayer-into-smaller-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, this is doable if you properly implement `renderLayer:inContext:` in your `CATiledLayer`-backed view.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test, and using renderInContext: on a view wrapping the scroll view seemed to work. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. I've put up some sample code which demonstrates this problem more succinctly: https://github.com/incanus/TiledLayerSnapTest Note that a capture of an ordinary `UIView` works fine, but the `CATiledLayer`-backed view comes up blank gray.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
- (UIImage *)snapshotImageWithView:(CCTiledImageScrollView *)view
{
// Try our best to approximate the best tile set zoom scale to use
CGFloat tileScale;
if (view.zoomScale >= 0.5) {
    tileScale = 2.0;
}
else if (view.zoomScale >= 0.25) {
    tileScale = 1.0;
}
else {
    tileScale = 0.5;
}

// Calculate the context translation based on how far zoomed in or out.
CGFloat translationX = -view.contentOffset.x;
CGFloat translationY = -view.contentOffset.y;
if (view.contentSize.width < CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds)) {
    CGFloat deltaX = (CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds) - view.contentSize.width) / 2.0;
    translationX += deltaX;
}
if (view.contentSize.height < CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds)) {
    CGFloat deltaY = (CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) - view.contentSize.height) / 2.0;
    translationY += deltaY;
}

// Pass the tileScale to the context because that will be the scale used in drawRect by your CATiledLayer backed UIView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds) / view.zoomScale, CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) / view.zoomScale), NO, tileScale);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, translationX / view.zoomScale, translationY / view.zoomScale);

// The zoomView is a subview of UIScrollView. The CATiledLayer backed UIView is a subview of the zoomView.
[view.zoomView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

}

Full sample code found here: https://github.com/gortega56/CCCanvasView